# Updating Tcl/Tk in MacOs Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: macos, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use dawn for Geant4 visualisation of .prim fils and I have managed to get the package. However, when I use it to visualise my files, the FUKUI Render DAWN (GUI ver.1Di) is mostly white and flickering, not showing all its part and making it impossible to use to generate my .eps file.
I think this may have something to do with Tcl/Tk version (currently Tcl 8.5 & Tk 8.5 (8.5.9). In fact, I get warnings such:

DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

WARNING: This version of tcl is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
In future versions of macOS the tcl runtime will not be available by
default, and may require you to install an additional package.

Do you think this might be the case? I was thinking of updating them, but I am not sure how to do that without compromising the environment or creating conflicts.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You can develop Tcl code for macOS without using Xcode therefore it must be deprecated in Apple's eyes.

Comment: Use Homebrew or Macports to obtain a fresh installation of Tcl/Tk which will not conflict with the onboard distribution.